# Split a string into several substrings using regex. Both matches and non-matches should be returned

Tags: java, regex

I would like to split a string into several substrings, and I think using regular expressions could help me.

```
I want this:        To become this:
<choice1>           {<choice1>}
c<hoi>ce2           {c, <hoi>, ce2}
<ch><oi><ce>3       {<ch>, <oi>, <ce>, 3}
choice4             {choice4}
```

Note that the curly brackets and comma's are just a visual aid. It doesn't really matter what the final form is, just that the values are seperately accessible/replacable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A String has a method split which will return an array of the parts that matched your regular expression. "asfdasdfadsf".split("regularExpression");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should work:

```
String str = "<ch><oi><ce>3";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>|\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find())
    System.out.printf("=> %s%n", m.group());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
=> <ch>
=> <oi>
=> <ce>
=> 3
```

Comment: given the examples, I think this would be simpler to grasp: <\\w+>|\\w+, but your answer is right too.

Answer (score 3):

With split

```
input.split("(?<!^)(?=<)|(?<=>)(?!$)");
```

---

Though I would match them

```
Matcher m=Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>|[^<>]+").matcher(input);
while(m.find())
{
     m.group();//matched value
}
```

Comment: +1 never mind the lame Matcher version. Your split regex rocks!